# Cakephp 3 validation without save

Tags: php, cakephp

I just started programming apps in Cakephp 3 and I am wondering how to validate user form data without saving or updating informations in the database?

Is there any solution to call validator to check if email is correct without further operations on database?

Comment: Isn't patching the entity enough? There are also [modelless forms](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html).

Comment: $article = $articles->patchEntity($article, $newData, [
    'validate' => 'sameValidationFunction'
]);

do it on this way?

Comment: I have form with email input and I need only check if email is valid or no. That's all and I do not know how to use validator

Comment: Then check out the source code behind http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/contact for example.

Comment: Hello Mark. Thank you for your example. Unfortunately this example is good when we have some forms etc. I would like to validate data in 20 actions wher next data will be an arguments of find function. I will not create forms